# how to make graph section of amcharts dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, amcharts

I am creating amcharts from database fields.Here is my code

```
function Categoriesline(data) {

                                                debugger;
                                                var databind = JSON.parse(data);
                                                var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
                                                    "theme": "light",
                                                    "type": "serial",
                                                    "legend": {
                                                    "position": "right",
                                                    "fontSize": 9
                                                     },                                                    
                                                    "marginRight": 80,
                                                    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
                                                    "marginTop": 20,
                                                    "dataProvider": databind,
                                                    "valueAxes": [{
                                                        "id": "v1",
                                                        "axisAlpha": 0.1
}],
                                                        "graphs": [{                                                            
                                                            "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b>value: [[value]]</b>",
                                                            "bullet": "round",
                                                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,                                                            
                                                            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                                                            "lineThickness": 2,
                                                            "title": "section1",
                                                            "valueField": "section1"
                                                        }, {
                                                            "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b>value: [[value]]</b>",
                                                            "bullet": "round",
                                                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,                                                            
                                                            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                                                            "lineThickness": 2,
                                                            "title": "section2",
                                                            "valueField": "section2"
                                                        }, {
                                                            "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b>value: [[value]]</b>",
                                                            "bullet": "round",
                                                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                                                            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                                                            "lineThickness": 2,
                                                            "title": "section3",
                                                            "valueField": "section3"
}],


                                                            "categoryField": "categorydescription",
                                                            "categoryAxis": {                                                                
                                                                "axisAlpha": 0,
                                                                "minHorizontalGap": 60
                                                            },
                                                            "export": {
                                                                "enabled": true
                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                    }
```

All required data from database i am fetching JSON format.

I want to specify the value axis from json itself.Here in above code instead of hardcoding "section1", "section2","section3" i want to assign it from databind object which is having json key name section.

How can i do this ?

I need to add something like

```
var graph = [];
                var v;
                for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    graph[j] = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                    graph[j].valueAxis =databind['section'] ; // we have to indicate which value axis should be used
                    graph[j].title = "Value" + j;
                    v = j.toString();
                    graph[j].valueField = databind['value'];
                    graph[j].bullet = "round";                    
                    chart.addGraph(graph[j]);
                }
```

Json format
[image]

[image]

In above pic foreach section i need different lines to draw(multiple line chart).

```
[
    {
"Section": "Section1",
        "duration": "1MCount",
        "value": 15},

    {
"Section": "Section2",
        "duration": "1MCount",
        "value": 20},

    {
"Section": "Section1",
        "duration": "3MCount",
        "value": 10},

    {
"Section": "Section2",
        "duration": "3MCount",
        "value": 7},

    {
"Section": "Section3",
        "duration": "3MCount",
        "value": 12}
]
```

i have added the json details.

Comment: Can you post how your JSON looks like?

Comment: @ martynasma: attached json format.Here 'duration' is my categoryaxis and i need to assign 'section1' ,'section2'...etc as value axis and 'value' as value field.pls help. How to set this dynamic value to value axis?

Comment: Thank you. But can you post the data in text format?

Comment: @martynasma :  i have added the json details from browser window in question.Is that enough?

Comment: No. Why can't you just post your data as a data, not as an image of data? If you want help you need to make it easy for people to help you. Why would you want to make them re-type your data?

Comment: [
 {
"Section": "Section1",
  "duration": "1MCount",
  "value": 15},

 {
"Section": "Section2",
  "duration": "1MCount",
  "value": 20},

 {
"Section": "Section1",
  "duration": "3MCount",
  "value": 10},

 {
"Section": "Section2",
  "duration": "3MCount",
  "value": 7},

 {
"Section": "Section3",
  "duration": "3MCount",
  "value": 12}
]

Comment: @martynasma :pls help

Comment: Is this a real data? Or just a fraction of it? Please understand, I honestly want to help, and I think I understand what you mean. But I don't want to go around guessing, please could you post your real data. I can't see how you expect the one you posted to produce multiple line graphs.

Comment: @martynasma: i created a sample JSON data.and my aim is to produce a multline charts where i want to draw a graph with category axes (1Mcount,3Mcount..) and values for respective section. can u tell me the format of JSON required for drawing the graph?